# How to issue commands using mconsole that runs in docker?

Tags: memgraphdb

I run the `memgraph-mage` image with `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 --name memgraph memgraph/memgraph-mage`

Most of the time I use Memgrpah Lab to send queries but I wanted to try out `mgconsole`. I run it using `docker exec -t memgraph mgconsole` but I can't enter any commands. My terminal looks like it is frozen, but at the same time I can use Memgraph Lab, and I can see that the the Memgraph docker is running.